# Single Point of Failure - data stream consumer (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm designing an architecture of a simple service that analyzes data (near-real-time analysis).

I have a data source which is my only data source and I assume that it is highly-available.
The current way I consume the data from this stream is by running an `EC2` machine (`AWS`) that reads the data from that stream and produces it to another stream (`Kinesis`).

My problem is that I cannot assume high-availability for the `EC2` machine.
Running more than one machine in parallel is bad idea since my data will be duplicated and each record will be processed twice (or as the number of `EC2` instances I run).

The availability of that machine is highly important as it provides me a continuous flow of data, which without it - my service worths nothing.

What can I do in order to achieve high-availability in this part of my architecture?

Comment: How is your ec2 instance getting the data from your data source? What protocol is it using?

Comment: HTTP. it is the Twitter public stream.

Comment: How about using autoscaling for your EC2 instances?

Comment: How does it solve my problem? the rules are as follows:
1. I can't miss a single record because of downtime.
2. I must process exactly once each record I consume.

It follows that having 2 or more instances connected to the Twitter stream results in duplicate records handled.

Comment: Any design which requires a singleton (in this case, one consumer which happens to be an EC2 instance) is going to be brittle and will not scale, no matter what infrastructure you run it on.

Comment: What do you suggest I do then? I must not miss a single record, then it follows I must have more than 2 instances at all times with a scaling group that, once one instance goes down, brings up a new one.

How do you suggest I handle duplicates?

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-record-processor-duplicates.html

Comment: @KarenB it does not help. I happen to use `ElasticSearch` in my service as well but I cannot rely on uniquely identifying records in `ES` to ignore dupes. That's because before a record gets to `ES` it goes through a pipeline and I will not let dupes go through the whole pipeline. **That's like paying 2x per record**.

Comment: This is what you should look into http://docs.aws.amazon.com/streams/latest/dev/kinesis-record-processor-scaling.html

Comment: @error2007s in what way does it help regarding this question? I've read it...

Comment: Ok on another note why do you need a EC2 instance to provide that data to kinesis? Is the EC2 instance processing the data in some way?

Comment: @error2007s, nope. It just listens on the Twitter stream and pushes those tweets to `Kinesis` stream.

If there's some other way to connect Twitter's stream (listen on HTTP) to `Kinesis` stream - I'm willing to hear :)

Comment: How many twitter feeds do you anticipate?

Comment: Practically I have access to only 1% of the stream (about 50 tweets /sec). But I would like to not rely on this piece of information as my service needs to be scalable.